# Operator precedence in Python 2.7

Tags: python

What is the value of `f`?

`f = lambda x: abs(x) if a == '1' else lambda x: x**2`

`f(2)` gives `lambda function` if `a = '1'` and `f(2)` gives `lambda function` if `a = '2'`.

What is the operator precedence here?

Comment: _"`f(2)` gives `lambda function` if `a = '1'`"_ No it doesn't? That returns `2`.

Comment: This question is horribly confusing and would benefit a lot from some rephrasing. It took me 3 minutes to figure out what you're even asking about, because there's no _operator_ precedence here (lambdas and conditionals aren't _operators_). Furthermore, it's unclear what you want `f` to be. Is `f` supposed to check the value of `a` every time it's called? Or should the value of `a` only be checked when `f` is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambda:` has a lower precedence than conditional expressions, as seen in [the operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) or by trying something like `lambda: 1 if False else 2` in the REPL.

Your statement parses as:

```
f = lambda x: (abs(x) if a == '1' else (lambda x: x**2))
```

Comment: if a='1' why f(1) is still lambda? Should be 1. lambda has lower precedence: why then else (lambda x: x**2)?

Comment: @AndrewFount: *“if a='1' why f(1) is still lambda?”* [It isn’t.](https://ideone.com/PTCmDI) *“why then else (lambda x: x**2)”?* `lambda` is a prefix so it can’t mean anything else.